# Custom element is always full width in WPBakery / Visual Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using the WordPress plugin WPBakery (was Visual Composer), where I've created custom elements.

In the editor side, any element can be placed in a row and it's columns can be defined from there, Is there a way to stop that?

For example, I have a custom element called `hero`. This block will always be `col-12` and prevent anything from being places besides this block.

Trying to prevent this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution? Because I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I added "ob_start" and "return ob_get_clean();" between file inclusion and that is work for me.

```
public static function output($atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(vc_map_get_attributes('myModule', $atts));
    ob_start();
    include_once('partials/public-display.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```